# C++ How to get a specific object in a class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I want to get a specific object in a class in C++. I looked into multiple sites and it seems my question is unique. Okay here's my code.

In House.h

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class House
{
    string Name;
    int Health;
public:
    House(string a, int h);
    void GetHouseStats();
    void DamageHouse(int d);
    ~House();
};
```

in House.cpp

```
#include "House.h"
#include <iostream>

House::House(string a, int h)
{
    Name = a;
    Health = h;
}
void House::DamageHouse(int d) {
Health -= d;
cout << "Your " << Name << " has " << Health << " left."<<endl;
}
void House::GetHouseStats() {
    cout << Name<<endl;
    cout << Health;
}
House::~House()
{
}
```

in Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "House.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    House Kubo("Bahay Kubo", 2);
    Kubo.DamageHouse(1);

}
```

I have House Kubo as my first object. I would like to save the person's houses into a file but my problem is **How can I pass the object's name into the function so that save its data into a file?** I can manually place the Kubo and do so as

```
PlayerHouse = Kubo.Name;
```

But what if I don't know which house I should save? Like instead of typing down

```
PlayerHouse = Apartment.Name;//2nd house
PlayerHouse = Modern.Name;//3rd house
```

Can I use an function argument to place the object's name into PlayerHouse? Like this

```
void SetHouseName(type object){
    PlayerHouse = object.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few ways in which this can be done .. is keeping all created object in a container and then access access the container to get the object in and pass it a function which will write it to a file .

Also if you do not want to maintain the container what you have mentioned about using the function will also work fine

Answer (score 0):

Of course, but if you are going to save the `Name` of the house anyway, why don't you just ask for a `std::string` in the first place and then pass the `Name` to that function?

```
void SetHouseName(std::string name)
{
  PlayerHouse = name;
}
```

If this is outside your `House` class you need to create a method to expose the `Name` member of `House` though, or just make it `public`.

To answer your initial question, just as how you would pass built-in types, you can do the same for your `House` type :

```
void SetHouseName(House house)
{
  PlayerHouse = house.Name;
}
```

Comment: Eh, actually not sure if OP is talking about the object name or the `Name` member of the class `House`, meh.

Comment: Tbh I don't want any of my class' objects to have public variables, because by then anywhere in the script some of my functions can edit the variables accidentally.

Comment: Then just get a `GetName() const` method in there.